# imageControl.Source (C# UWP)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I writing app for uwp

I have PCL, where is method for opening Camera, taking photo and saving it.

Here is code for method in PCL.

```
public async void PhotoTake()
    {
        CameraCaptureUI captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
        captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
        captureUI.PhotoSettings.CroppedSizeInPixels = new Size(200, 200);
        StorageFile photo = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

        if (photo == null)
        {

            return;
        }
        StorageFolder destinationFolder =
        await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("ProfilePhotoFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        await photo.CopyAsync(destinationFolder, "ProfilePhoto.jpg", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await photo.DeleteAsync();

        IRandomAccessStream stream = await photo.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
        SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
        SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmapBGR8 = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap,
        BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
        BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

        SoftwareBitmapSource bitmapSource = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
        await bitmapSource.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmapBGR8);


    }
```

In xaml I have Image. I need to display photo in this Image.

As I understood I need to write smth like this `imageControl.Source = bitmapSource;`

But my when I write it I have
`Error  CS0103  The name 'bitmapSource' does not exist in the current context`

Here is my xaml.cs file

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

         CameraOpening cam = new CameraOpening();
         cam.PhotoTake();
        imageControl.Source = bitmapSource;

    }


}
```

How I hadle this error?

Thank's

Comment: Man, did you try to dig into C# first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bitmapSource` is a local variable inside your method. You can't access it from outside.

Change the method's return type from `void` to `Task<SoftwareBitmapSource>` and delete the image file after creating the bitmap:

```
public async Task<SoftwareBitmapSource> PhotoTake()
{
    var captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
    captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
    captureUI.PhotoSettings.CroppedSizeInPixels = new Size(200, 200);

    var photo = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
    var bitmapSource = new SoftwareBitmapSource();

    if (photo != null)
    {
        var folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(
            "ProfilePhotoFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        await photo.CopyAsync(folder, "ProfilePhoto.jpg",
            NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        using (var stream = await photo.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
            var softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
            var softwareBitmapBGR8 = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(
                softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

            await bitmapSource.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmapBGR8);
        }

        await photo.DeleteAsync();
    }

    return bitmapSource;
}
```

Then await the method call. As this can't be done in the Page's contructor, you may do it in a `Loaded` event handler:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += async (o, e) =>
    {
        var cam = new CameraOpening();

        imageControl.Source = await cam.PhotoTake();
    };
}
```